# 2020 Community Moderator Election - Results

Tags: discussion, election

Photography's [seventh moderator election](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/7) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Philip Kendall] [image: scottbb]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/7), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6266019770269696/0).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the community for the vote of confidence, congratulations to scottbb and thanks to our existing mods for all the work they do.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to everybody who participated. I'd also like to congratulate Philip, he's been around a long time, and will definitely make a great mod. Finally, Thanks to Michael C for diving on the nomination grenade to ensure we had an election, even though he preferred not to get into the moderation racket.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, Philip and Scott! We all owe you (and Michael C) a big thank-you for volunteering to help keep this community alive.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent choices all round - congratulations to our two new mods, Philip Kendal & scottbb.

And special recognition to Michael C for 'filling up the numbers' whilst not wanting to be chosen. A daring move, well taken.
I had similar thoughts myself just to get the election going, but I'm definitely not qualified by dint of skill [or lack thereof] and also temperament. Michael stepped in and saved me the embarrassment ;)

I voted Michael 3rd in recognition of a task done for the community, rather than self.